# Installing WSF on ubuntu linux issue

Tags: php, ubuntu, openssl, wsh

I'm trying to request to a web service which is using WS Security and based on signing method(private public keys), as I've successfully installed wsf library but still when I hit the url it generate these error logs.

REQUEST URL
http://localhost/wsf/samples/security/signing/client.php

RESPONSE
Message = ws client create failed

Error Log GENERATED in wsf_c/logs

[Fri Feb  3 15:00:23 2012] [error] class_loader.c(152) Loading shared library /opt/lampp/htdocs/wsf/wsf_c/lib/libaxis2_http_receiver.so  Failed. DLERROR IS /opt/lampp/htdocs/wsf/wsf_c/lib/libaxis2_http_receiver.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

```
[Fri Feb  3 15:00:23 2012] [error] conf_builder.c(1156) Transport receiver loading failed for libaxis2_http_receiver.so, unable to continue

[Fri Feb  3 15:00:23 2012] [error] conf_builder.c(263) Processing transport receivers failed, unable to continue

[Fri Feb  3 15:00:23 2012] [error] dep_engine.c(928) Populating Axis2 Configuration failed

[Fri Feb  3 15:00:23 2012] [error] conf_init.c(225) Loading deployment engine failed for client repository /opt/lampp/htdocs/wsf/wsf_c

[Fri Feb  3 15:03:01 2012] [error] class_loader.c(152) Loading shared library /opt/lampp/htdocs/wsf/wsf_c/lib/libaxis2_http_receiver.so  Failed. DLERROR IS /opt/lampp/htdocs/wsf/wsf_c/lib/libaxis2_http_receiver.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Someone kindly tell me how to fix it Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the libraries in the wrong place, (but they could be entirely correct for your system)
Do any of the other samples work for you?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and have them in 
`'/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/wfc/lib'`

you might need to set your wfc.home Directive in your php.ini
I have the following in `/etc/php5/conf.d/wsf.ini`
(my Apache/php loads all the ini files under conf.d on startup)

```
; configuration for php WSF module
extension=wsf.so
include_path=".:/usr/share/php:/home/haydn/Downloads/wso2/scripts"
[wsf]
wsf.home="/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/wsf_c"
```

Hope This Helps